# Show that $a_0\leq \alpha \le a_0 +1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, continued-fractions

It is given that $$\alpha=[a_0;a_1,a_2,...,a_n]$$ where $a_0,...,a_n$ are all positive integers.

We need to show that 
$$a_0\leq \alpha \le a_0 +1$$

My question is when the equality holds ? I guess the question is wrong ... there can't be the equality sign in the question as these are positive integers.

Comment: Can you post the screen shot?

Comment: $x<y \implies x \leqslant y$.  Equality is not necessary for the latter to hold true.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't wrong. Note that it is true, for example, that $2\leq 2.5\leq 3$. It is also true that $2<2.5<3$. Just because the strict inequality is true does not mean the inequality with the equal signs is false. In fact, the strict inequality implies the one with equal signs. Indeed, the statement is true because
$$ \alpha=a_0+\underbrace{\frac{1}{a_1+\frac{1}{a_2+\frac1{a_3+\frac1\ddots}}}}_{\mathrm{strictly\ between}\ 0\ \mathrm{and}\ 1}. $$

Comment: yes that is what i want to ask... i got only between open intervals ... not closed

Comment: @learningstudent The case between open intervals implies the closed interval case. I don't see any problem at all.

Comment: When the equality holds ??? if equality doesn't hold in any case ,,, then we cant represent it in closed forms

Comment: @learningstudent Do you think it is true that $2\leq 2.5$? But equality never holds!

Comment: i got what you said ...  but while proving we can't apply extra equality if it never holds.... if in an inequality .. while substituting some values and we obtain 2<= 2.5 then it is okay..!

Comment: @learningstudent I don't understand what you're trying to say. You already know the strict inequality to be true, which implies the inequality in the question, so it is already solved!

Comment: $\le$ means "less than *or* equal to." Remember that "or" is inclusive in math. In this case, equality is possible when $\alpha = a_0$ or $\alpha = a_0 + 1$, and the statement is still true even if $\alpha$ is not strictly between two integers.

Comment: @Bladewood for what values of a_1,..a_n $\alpha=a_0$

Comment: Nevermind, I should have read the problem more carefully. Even still, @YiFan is correct that if $a_0 \lt \alpha \lt a_0 + 1$, it is still true that $a_0 \le \alpha \le a_0 + 1$ - even if it is always true that $\alpha \neq a_0$ or $\alpha \neq a_0 + 1$. However, I now agree with you that the problem is poorly worded in that regard.